# ASP.NET application accessing network share

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI application that needs to be able to write files to a network share. I've created an Active Directory account with the correct permissions, and set up the application pool to run as it. However, file operations still return an "Access Denied" error.

What else should I check?

**Update:**
I've also tried impersonation, but that has the same result.

**Update 2:**
It seems that even setting "Everyone" to have access doesn't seem to help. I can manually map a drive using the appropriate credentials, but I can't access that path in the context of the application.

Comment: what permission you have for appool?

Comment: @Rahul: I'm sorry. I don't understand the question. If you are referring to the user that the application pool is running as. It has Read and Change permission to the share itself.

Comment: NO, I mean what's the access level your appool is running on?

Comment: @Rahul: Do you mean trust level? The application is running with full trust.